# Node Class member function not working in Linked List Bag

Tags: c++, linked-list, bag

I seem to be having difficulty activating a class member function for a node class that i am trying to implement in array class for a linked list. I would appreciate any assistance in pointing out the problem. These are the relevant code blocks:

```
    #ifndef LINK_H
    #define LINK_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>


    namespace linkedlist{

    class node {

    typedef size_t value_type;

    private:
        value_type m_data;
        node *m_link;

public: 
        //Constructor
        node(const value_type& i_data = value_type(), node* i_link = NULL){
            m_data = i_data;
            m_link = i_link;
        }
    void list_copy (const node* source_ptr, node*& head_ptr, node*& tail_ptr);
```

For the implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Link.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace linkedlist;

void node::list_copy (const node* source_ptr, node*& head_ptr, node*& tail_ptr){
    head_ptr = NULL;
    tail_ptr = NULL;
    // Handle the case of the empty list.
    if (source_ptr == NULL) return;
    // Make the head node for the newly created list, and put data in it.
    list_head_insert(head_ptr, source_ptr->data( ));
    tail_ptr = head_ptr;
    // Copy the rest of the nodes one at a time, adding at the tail of new list.
    source_ptr = source_ptr->link( );
    while (source_ptr != NULL) {
    list_insert(tail_ptr, source_ptr->data( ));
    tail_ptr = tail_ptr->link( );
    source_ptr = source_ptr->link( );
    }
}
```

Link Listed Bag

```
    #ifndef ARLINK_H
    #define ARLINK_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include "Link.h"

    using namespace linkedlist;

class bag{

typedef size_t size_type;
typedef node::value_type value_type;

private:
    node *head_ptr; //list head pointer
    size_type m_nodes; //number of nodes in the list

public:
    // CONSTRUCTORS and DESTRUCTOR
    bag( );
    bag(const bag& source){
        node *tail_ptr; // Needed for argument to list_copy
        list_copy(source.head_ptr, head_ptr, tail_ptr); //Giving Error Link List definition not resolved
        m_nodes = source.m_nodes;
    }
```

node::list_copy is not recognized

Comment: `list_copy` is a private member function of `node`. The `bag` class doesn't have access to it.

Comment: wait sorry, I made an error writing the question, it is actually in the public section.

Comment: I have now corrected the question... I apologize for not copying the code over properly...

Comment: It's still a member function of `node`, so you'll need to call it through an instance of `node`. You're calling it in `bag` as if it's a free function.

Comment: can you show me how I can do that?

Comment: E.g., `tail_ptr->list_copy(...)`. If you make it a static function, then you can just do `node::list_copy(...)`. Depending on what you're doing, you can probably also just move it out of `node` entirely.

Comment: i tried doing that (node::) it did not work.

Comment: `node::` won't work unless you declare the function as `static` (`static void` instead of just `void`).

Comment: interestingly I actually sent back to see what error was in node:: and it seems that there is problem with initialization of head_ptr.

Comment: i seem to be having difficulty implementing any member function of node class despite there being a node class variable in my private variables